# TypeError: json() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' Python, Github API

Tags: python, python-3.x, github-api

I need to get all the GitHub branches of a certain repository. Using the GitHub API as documented here, https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/branches/#list-branches I try to use the GET request documented.

However, when I try unit testing, I get `TypeError: json() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'` at `if len(response.json()) == 0:`

```
class GithubService:

    @staticmethod
    def get_branches(git_base, org, repo):

        github_repo_url = f"https://api.github.com/repos/{org}/{repo}"
        collected_all_branches: bool = False
        page = 1
        github_branches = []
        # collect all branches in repo
        while not collected_all_branches:
            response = (requests.get(f"{github_repo_url}/branches/?per_page=100&page={page}",
                                     headers=HEADERS))
            print("response")
            print(response)
            if len(response.json()) == 0:
                collected_all_branches = True
            else:
                github_branches.extend([response["name"] for response in response.json()])
            page = page + 1
        return github_branches
```

Unit Test:

```
    @patch.object(requests, "get", return_value=Response)
    def test_get_branches(self, mock_get):

        GithubService.get_branches("test", "test", "test")
        mock_get.assert_called_with("test", "test", "test")
```

Comment: Provide your class with __init__

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: @Valerii I included the name of the class